# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in kivy file

Tags: python, kivy

Hello guys i hope you are doing well

so  i'm trying to build an android application with python and kivy using visual studio code

first thing i create a python file (signin.py)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class SigninWindow(BoxLayout):
    pass

class SigninApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SigninWindow()

if __name__=="__main__":
    sa = SigninApp()
    sa.run()
```

second thing i create a kivy file (signin.kv)

```
#:kivy 1.1.1
<SigninWindow>:
orientation: 'vertical'
spacing: 10
BoxLayout:
size_hint_y: None
height: 50
Label:
text: 'Access Control'
bold: True
size_hint_x: .9
    Button:
        text: 'x'
        size_hint_x: .1 
    BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            hint_text: 'Username'
        TextInput:
            hint_text: 'Password'
    Button:
        text: 'Se Connecter'
```

But when i run the programm, Nothing appears and they told me that

```
 <SigninWindow>:



 ^


SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The indentation of your code is broken.

Comment: what that's mean ? can you please give me a solution !!

Comment: no this is not the problem , in the visual studio code i respect the indentation , when i copied the code here i didin't respect the indentation

Comment: _what that's mean ?_ Look at the first snippet of Python in your post, all the code starts at the same level, despite there being a function definition and two classes which do require indentation.

Comment: Fixed indentation

Comment: @NouraGhana Indentation also applies to .kv

Answer (score 1):

When I copy/paste your code (and correct the indentation), everything seems to be working fine.

The first time I tried to run your code, I accidentally typed `python signin.kv` in place of `python signin.py` and I got exactly the same error as you. Maybe your problem comes from there.